# Tomcat server status page does not show all details

Tags: tomcat, tomcat9

I upgraded my Tomcat webserver recently from version **8.0.30** to **9.0.13**.

But the manager/status page does not show all the details as before. Does anyone have an idea what could be the reason? I have compared the files from both the versions and they seem the same.

I'm attaching some screenshots of the *Tomcat Web Application Manager -> Server Status* page for both the versions below.

**Version 8.0.30**
[image]

**Version 9.0.13**

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Exception found in logs:

> 21-Dec-2018 10:52:22.732 SEVERE [http-nio-8181-exec-46] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [Status] in context with path [/manager] threw exception [javax.management.AttributeNotFoundException:  Cannot find attribute maxThreads for org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProperties@556cee20] with root cause
>    javax.management.AttributeNotFoundException:  Cannot find attribute maxThreads for org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProperties@556cee20
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.ManagedBean.getGetter(ManagedBean.java:434)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.getAttribute(BaseModelMBean.java:167)
>           at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.getAttribute(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:647)
>           at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.getAttribute(JmxMBeanServer.java:678)
>           at org.apache.catalina.manager.StatusTransformer.writeConnectorState(StatusTransformer.java:304)
>           at org.apache.catalina.manager.StatusManagerServlet.doGet(StatusManagerServlet.java:336)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>           at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:607)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:668)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
>           at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>           at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:791)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1417)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: Please add error logs to your question and mention the details you are missing. I see that page stopped rendering after "Max threads:" which might indicate you'll find exceptions in your logs.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've added the exception now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Looks like there is already a solved issue addressing this](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62918).

It claims this is fixed in Tomcat 9.0.14 and 8.5.36 which are both released already. Please upgrade and verify.

Comment: Thank you @Selaron. Upgrading to the next version worked. I also see they've removed listing of downloads for version 9.0.13 https://www.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-9/

Answer (score -1):

My tomcat version is 8.5.47, also met this error.

```
Cannot find attribute maxThreads for org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProperties@526c0a99
```